# delphi DATA Export to Word

Tags: delphi, ms-word

I'm using Delphi 2010 and Fastreport 4. I have a problem.
Fastreport exporting to word as RTF file. DATA is being shown as table.
I don`t need table. I just want to see plain text (with UTF-8 support)
Example to want I want to see:

```
-HEADER-

1. Halil Polat (Name surname)

Origin: Ankara

Birth date: 15.05.1980

Graduated from: Manhattan university


2. Aslı Gungor

Origin: Bursa

Birth date: 05.07.1979

Graduated from: Oxford university


3. Tunch Demir

Origin: İzmir

Birth date: 21.11.1981

Graduated from: Harvard University
```

Can you help me, please?